# how to not show some item in listview

Tags: android, json, listview

i want to make some of item in my listview are not showing in my listview and i get the data from json. i don't know what code should i write to make some items in listview not showing in list or how the best practice for it.

this is my code

```
String nama = ar.getString("nama");
                String status = ar.getString("status");
                String keterangan = ar.getString("keterangan");
                String tanggal = ar.getString("updated_at");
                idaset = ar.getInt("id");
                foto = ar.getString("foto");

                if (ar.has("asset_parent") && !ar.isNull("asset_parent")) {
                    JSONObject parent = ar.getJSONObject("asset_parent");
                    nama2 = parent.getString("nama");

                    if (parent.has("asset_parent") && !parent.isNull("asset_parent")) {
                        JSONObject parent2 = parent.getJSONObject("asset_parent");
                        nama3 = parent2.getString("nama");

                    }
                }
                if (status == "1") {
                    //code for not showing the row in listview
                } else {
                    if (tanggal.equals("null"))
                        reports.add(new Word(nama, nama3, nama2, "", foto, keterangan, idaset));
                    else
                        reports.add(new Word(nama, nama3, nama2, tanggal, foto, keterangan, idaset));
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_view1);

                adapter = new WordAdapter(UpdateActivity.this, reports, R.color.putih);
                final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);


                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is the pojo that i make to make the list

```
public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int colorResourceId) {
    super(context, 0, words);
    mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.isi_listview, parent, false);
    }

    Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    TextView asetTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    asetTextView.setText(currentWord.getAset());
    TextView ruangTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text4);
    ruangTextView.setText(currentWord.getRuang());
    TextView tanggalTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
    tanggalTextView.setText(currentWord.getTanggal());

    View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),mColorResourceId);
    textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return listItemView;
}
```

please help how to do it well

Comment: share your data that recieve in json we will add check on basis of that

Comment: i already add it @AhsanMalik

Comment: is there any variable on the basis of that we can add check in our code ?

Comment: i already add the pojo